# Operators before the function call

Tags: javascript

Today I figured out that it is possible to use operations before the parenthesis of a function call.

E.g.

```
console.log|('Hello world!');
```

or

```
console.log>>(33);
```

Why is this possible and what happens?

Comment: `console.log|('Hello world!');` same as `console.log | 'Hello world!'`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like in most "algol-like" languages, parentheses have multiple meanings in javascript:

- grouping operator, as in `2 * (3 + 4)`
- function call operator, as in `console.log(5)`
- part of function declaration syntax: `function(x) {}`

When you insert an operator between a function name and a function call parenthesis, this one becomes the grouping operator. It's not a function call anymore. So `func(args)` turns into `func op (args)`, which is syntactically a valid expression, because functions are "first-class citizens" in javascript and can be used in expressions like any other value. Whether it makes sense is another question though, because, apart from `+`, operators don't produce anything meaningful when applied to functions.

Comment: _"apart from `+`, operators don't produce anything meaningful when applied to functions"_ I beg to differ: property accessors (`[]` and `.`) _do_ add value. `someFunction.toString = function(){return 'custom behavior';};` _can_ be useful, and can be used to have function objects behave a certain way when other operators are being used

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are not executing the function, you are just evaluating an expression (that makes no sense at all)

The `console.log|('Hello world!')`, will be evaluated as:

```
[native function] | 'Hello world!'
```

Which makes no sense, since "|" is a bitwise operator. Same as the other example that you gave.

So, you are not placing the operator between the function call. You are separating the values, and no longer performing the expected action (funcion call).

Comment: nit-pick: `console.log|('Hello world!')` is performing _"the action"_ as far as JS is concerned. The action it performs just isn't a function call anymore ;-P

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - True :) - Rephrased

Answer (score 1):

Simply put: because an operator works on operands, and functions are, in JS at least, first class objects (meaning they can be passed around, and returned, and operated on).

To do so, you'll of course need to use operators. A simple, not too far fetched example:

```
function foo()
{
    return foo.bar;//. is an operator
}
console.log(foo());//logs undefined
foo.bar = '123';//again, the . operator
console.log(foo());//logs 123
```

What happens in your case, however, is JS will evaluate both operands (the expressions on either side of the operator):

```
console.log (LOperand)
| (operator)
('hello world') (ROperand, to be evaluated further still because of the grouping operator ())
```

And attempt to evaluate them to compatible types for the operator to do its work. `console.log` is an object, a function instance in fact. `hello world` is a string constant inside a the grouping operator.
How these types will be coerced and evaluated is specified in the ECMAScript standard (google it), but bottom line, the function (`console.log`) could well be coerced to a string (as if you'd call `console.log.toString()`, which gives `"function log() { [native code] }"` on chromium). The upshot is that the code behaves the same as:

```
"function log() { [native code] }"|"Hello world"
```

which yields `0`

Answer (score 1):

> It is possible to use operations before the parenthesis of a function call.

Not quite so,

```
console.log|('Hello world!');
```

is equivalent to

```
console.log | 'Hello world!';
```

which has a different meaning than you intended :)

---

`('Hello world!')` is the same as `'Hello world!'` and `|` is the [bitwise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) **OR** operator in JavaScript (`left | right` will match the left operand with the right operand *bit by bit*).

In your example, `console.log` *without* parenthesis returns the function itself (as opposed to `console.log()` which returns `undefined`), so you are basically `[Function] | 'Hello world!'`.